# Why is the new python "print(x)" function better than the old "print x" approach?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've had to follow an example recently that encouraged me to use the new style python `print()` function, which I can only access after `from __future__ import print_function`.  What are the major differences between the two?  What was the old `print`, if not a function?

Comment: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/

Comment: What it *wasn't* was an object - and that kind of goes against python's everything-is-an-object ethos.  Practically, function-print has some new features, and occasionally it's useful to pass `print` as an argument to some other function.

Comment: @roippi Never knew about passing print. Why is it useful? It's built in and you can use it anywhere.

Comment: @aIKid hard to explain concisely, but it's a debugging thing.  If you have a collection of callable functions that you're sequentially doing something to (i.e. a `map`-like operation) you can toss `print` in there and do some quick introspection.

Answer (score 5):

The old `print` is  a statement. It's not really bad by any means, it's convenient to use and easy to type. However, making it a function brings a lot of new functionalities.

This is some arguments that Guido mounted himself:

- print is the only application-level functionality that has a statement dedicated to it. Within Python's world, syntax is generally used as a last resort, when something can't be done without help from the compiler. Print doesn't qualify for such an exception.
- At some point in application development one quite often feels the need to replace print output by something more sophisticated, like logging calls or calls into some other I/O library. With a print() function, this is a straightforward string replacement, today it is a mess adding all those parentheses and possibly converting >>stream style syntax.
- Having special syntax for print puts up a much larger barrier for evolution, e.g. a hypothetical new printf() function is not too far fetched when it will coexist with a print() function.
- There's no easy way to convert print statements into another call if one needs a different separator, not spaces, or none at all. Also, there's no easy way at all to conveniently print objects with some other separator than a space.
- If print() is a function, it would be much easier to replace it within one module (just def print(*args):...) or even throughout a program (e.g. by putting a different function in **builtin**.print). As it is, one can do this by writing a class with a write() method and assigning that to sys.stdout -- that's not bad, but definitely a much larger conceptual leap, and it works at a different level than print.

Source: [PEP 3105](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/)

Answer (score 0):

`print` is a keyword, and `print()` is a function. For almost all purposes that I have encountered, `print(x)` (python 3.x) will work just like `print x` (python 2.x). However, you cannot use the comma to avoid going to a new line any more. Instead, you must use `print(x, end=k)`, where `k` is a string that whatever you will print out after printing out `x`. For most purposes, you can use `k = ''` to avoid going to a new line.

Comment: Hmm, the function form seems a lot less convenient.

Comment: Depends on your application. If you wanted to print a certain keyword at the end of each line of a file, then it would be useful to use print(line, end = "<keyword>")

Comment: you could do this even more easily the old way with `print line, keyword`  Also, if I'm not mistaken, your approach will string all the lines together, since you've over-written the default `\n` line ending.

Comment: Then I could do print(line, end="<keyword>\n")